# Calculation method for model with different has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, associations, has-many

I wrote a method that calculations a certain value for a business case.

My models look like this

```
class CEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bcase
end

class SEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bcase
end

class CnqEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :bcase
end

class Bcase < ActiveRecord::Base
         has_many :c_entries, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :s_entries, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :cnq_entries, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

Now I wrote this method for the business case model

```
def int_rc
    x = 0
    self.c_entries.where(:hours != 0 && :order_no !=).each do |entry|
        x = x + (entry.hours * entry.rate.ratevalue)
    end
    return x.round(2)
end
```

But I need this for c_entries, s_entries and cnq_entries and I guess it would be stupid to write it 3 times because it would be 90% the same.

So what I try is set it variable and fill it with the right object type. Thats what I have and is not working:

```
def int_rc(type)
    x = 0
    self.type.where(:hours != 0 && :order_no !=).each do |entry|
        x = x + (entry.hours * entry.rate.ratevalue)
    end
    return x.round(2)
end
```

And then I would call `@bcase.int_rc(c_entries)`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close; using the [Ruby `send` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send) is what you're after. You can use `send` to build dynamic methods, passing it a symbol or a string. The last three lines here are equivalent; try it in [`irb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell):

```
a = "example"
a.chars # ['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
a.send :chars
a.send "chars"
```

You can also pass arguments to `send`:

```
a = "example"
a.index('m') # 3
a.send :index, 'm' # equivalent to the above
```

---

So, your `int_rc` method should work as follows:

```
def int_rc(type)
    x = 0
    self.send(type).where(:hours != 0 && :order_no !=).each do |entry|
        x = x + (entry.hours * entry.rate.ratevalue)
    end
    return x.round(2)
end
```